# How to apply css class on hover for just one html element

Tags: html, css

i have a span like below :

```
<span  class="fa fa-fw fa-close">
```

and i want to have the fa-close in red color on hover,
when I create the css class :

```
.fa-close:hover{color :red;}
```

it is applied to all spans with fa-close but i want it to be applied for just one span. How can i do it please?

Comment: Do you know the index of the `span`, and is it always the same? Can you use a more specific selector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add extra class to specific `span` where you want to apply red colour

For example

HTML

```
<span  class="fa fa-fw fa-close extra">
```

and CSS like

```
.fa-close.extra {color :red;}
```

So now, wherever you want to apply red colour you can add this class.

> Hope this helps :)

**Update as per PO requirement**

If you want red colour only on hover then your code be like below

HTML

```
<span  class="fa fa-fw fa-close extra">
```

and CSS like

```
.fa-close.extra:hover {color :red;}
```

Comment: in fact i want this red color to be applied on hover of fa-close any ideas please?

Comment: @gatkipper use css for hover instead of normal `.fa-close.extra:hover {color :red;}`

Comment: thank's for your reply , but the color is set red by default

Comment: remove `.fa-close.extra {color :red;}` and add `.fa-close.extra:hover {color :red;}`

Answer (score 0):

Apply internal css to that span only:`<span  class="fa fa-fw fa-close" style=color:red>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply css to only one element then you should use id instead of class.

#fa-close{color :red;}

Answer (score -1):

Add new class in span and then write `css` by using that class

**HTML**

```
<span  class="fa fa-fw fa-close apply_only_one">
```

**CSS**

```
.apply_only_one.fa-close{color :red;}
```

This is the best solution of your Problem.

Comment: why the copy of the same answer from another user?

Comment: not copy when i uploaded answer after writing ...then i saw that someone else also gave the same answer